# How do you minimize the nesting level within a function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I'm currently getting this error:

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Line 127
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

How can I minimize the nesting level? I did some research and saw that someone had used go each end but that didn't work for me.

```
--Function: StateFilingStatus
create function dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(@EmpFederalFilingStatus char(1), @EmpTransferState char(2))
returns char(1)
as
begin
    declare @StateFilingStatus char;

    if (@EmpTransferState = 'MS') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end
    else if (@EmpTransferState = 'NJ') 
    begin
         if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
             set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
         else
             set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
    end
    else if (@EmpTransferState = 'AZ') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
    end
    else if (@EmpTransferState = 'CT') 
    begin
         if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'F';
         else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end
    else if (@EmpTransferState = 'DC') 
    begin
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'Y';
    end
    else
    begin   
        if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
        else
            set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
    end

    return (select dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(EmpFederalFilingStatus, EmpTransferState) as StateFilingStatus
            from EmployeeTransfers)
end
go

select dbo.GetStateFilingStatus('M','NJ')  as StateFilingStatus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your nesting problem is from incorrectly formed `return`.

Instead of:

```
return(
    select dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(EmpFederalFilingStatus, EmpTransferState) as StateFilingStatus
    from EmployeeTransfers
)
```

You would use:

```
  return @StateFilingStatus;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DJM36125

```
--Function: StateFilingStatus
create function dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(
    @EmpFederalFilingStatus char(1)
  , @EmpTransferState char(2)
  )
returns char(1) as
begin;
  declare @StateFilingStatus char(1);
  if (@EmpTransferState = 'MS') 
  begin;
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
  end;
  else
  if (@EmpTransferState = 'NJ') 
  begin;
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
  end;
  else
  if (@EmpTransferState = 'AZ') 
  begin;
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'A';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'B';
  end;
  else
  if (@EmpTransferState = 'CT') 
  begin;
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'F';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
  end;
  else
  if (@EmpTransferState = 'DC') 
  begin;
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'Y';
  end;
  else
  begin   
    if (@EmpFederalFilingStatus = 'S')
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'S';
    else
      set @StateFilingStatus = 'M';
  end;
  return @StateFilingStatus;
end;
go
select StateFilingStatus = dbo.GetStateFilingStatus('','NJ');
```

returns `A`

And since this is a scalar function, you would query with it using:

```
select 
    et.EmpFederalFilingStatus
  , StateFilingStatus = dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(et.EmpFederalFilingStatus,et.EmpTransferState)
from EmployeeTransfers et
```

---

Scalar functions like this can cause horrible performance issues. Whenever possible, functions should be written as in-line table valued functions.

If this is anything except for a learning exercise, I would recommend using a crosswalk table (as my other answer explains).

Reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: It is purely for a learning exercise, as you said. I'll be trying the crosswalk table next with another database. I do have a question about the 'et.' you used, what does that refer to?

Comment: @Danny That is an alias for the table name `EmployeeTransfers` so we don't have to type `EmployeeTransfers` all over the place to specify the table of a column. `from EmployeeTransfers et` is the same as `from EmployeeTransfers as et`. here is an example: http://rextester.com/SLLD96236

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling all of this on a case by case basis, why not create a crosswalk table?

```
create table Filing_State_xwalk (
    TransferState char(2) not null
  , FederalStatus char(1) not null
  , StateStatus   char(1) not null
  , constraint pk_Filing_State_xwalk 
      primary key (TransferState, FederalStatus)
);
insert into Filing_State_xwalk values
 ('MS','S','A')
,('MS',' ','M')
,('NJ','S','B')
,('NJ',' ','A')
,('AZ','S','A')
,('AZ',' ','M')
,('CT','S','F')
,('CT',' ','M')
,('DC','S','S')
,('DC',' ','Y');
```

And use it in a procedure like so:

```
set @StateFilingStatus = (
  select StateStatus
  from Filing_State_xwalk
  where TransferState = @EmpTransferState
    and FederalStatus = coalesce(@EmpFederalFilingStatus,' ')
);
```

Or join to it directly from queries instead of calling a function.

Comment: I'm trying to get the hang of user-defined functions, as i'm not so knowledgeable with them. Procedures I understand more clearly. In order to join the query with the function would it be 'select EmpFederalFilingStatus from EmployeeTransfers where EmpFederalFilingStatus = @EmpFederalFilingStatus  and StateFilingStatus = StateFilingStatus'